# How to search for part of a string with Azure Cognitive Search

Tags: azure, search, azure-blob-storage, azure-cognitive-search

I'm quite new to Azure Cognitive Search, and have succeded to configure my index in order to have autocompletion (using partial search thanks to [this article](https://medium.com/cloud-maker/azure-search-implementing-partial-word-search-c770cd052f39)).

But now I have another use case where I have many files stored in an Azure Blob Container with metadata:

One of the metadata field (of each file) is called **partnumbers** and its value is a string of products SKU separated with a comma (like "123456,78901,102938,09876").
I've built my index in order to store this info as a **Edm.String**, as you can see below:

```
{
  "name": "my-index",
  "fields": [
    {
      "name": "partnumbers",
      "type": "Edm.String",
      "facetable": true,
      "filterable": true,
      "key": false,
      "retrievable": true,
      "searchable": true,
      "sortable": true,
      "analyzer": null,
      "indexAnalyzer": null,
      "searchAnalyzer": null,
      "synonymMaps": [],
      "fields": []
    },
    {
      "name": "metadata_storage_name",
      "type": "Edm.String",
      "facetable": true,
      "filterable": true,
      "key": false,
      "retrievable": false,
      "searchable": true,
      "sortable": true,
      "analyzer": null,
      "indexAnalyzer": null,
      "searchAnalyzer": null,
      "synonymMaps": [],
      "fields": []
    },
    {
      "name": "metadata_storage_content_type",
      "type": "Edm.String",
      "facetable": true,
      "filterable": true,
      "key": false,
      "retrievable": false,
      "searchable": true,
      "sortable": true,
      "analyzer": null,
      "indexAnalyzer": null,
      "searchAnalyzer": null,
      "synonymMaps": [],
      "fields": []
    },
    {
      "name": "metadata_storage_last_modified",
      "type": "Edm.String",
      "facetable": true,
      "filterable": true,
      "key": false,
      "retrievable": false,
      "searchable": true,
      "sortable": true,
      "analyzer": null,
      "indexAnalyzer": null,
      "searchAnalyzer": null,
      "synonymMaps": [],
      "fields": []
    },
    {
      "name": "metadata_storage_path",
      "type": "Edm.String",
      "facetable": true,
      "filterable": true,
      "key": false,
      "retrievable": false,
      "searchable": true,
      "sortable": true,
      "analyzer": null,
      "indexAnalyzer": null,
      "searchAnalyzer": null,
      "synonymMaps": [],
      "fields": []
    },
    {
      "name": "metadata_storage_size",
      "type": "Edm.Int64",
      "facetable": true,
      "filterable": true,
      "retrievable": false,
      "sortable": true,
      "analyzer": null,
      "indexAnalyzer": null,
      "searchAnalyzer": null,
      "synonymMaps": [],
      "fields": []
    },
    {
      "name": "key",
      "type": "Edm.String",
      "facetable": true,
      "filterable": true,
      "key": true,
      "retrievable": true,
      "searchable": true,
      "sortable": true,
      "analyzer": null,
      "indexAnalyzer": null,
      "searchAnalyzer": null,
      "synonymMaps": [],
      "fields": []
    },
    {
      "name": "partialPartnumbers",
      "type": "Edm.String",
      "facetable": false,
      "filterable": false,
      "key": false,
      "retrievable": false,
      "searchable": true,
      "sortable": false,
      "analyzer": null,
      "indexAnalyzer": "prefixCmAnalyzer",
      "searchAnalyzer": "standardCmAnalyzer",
      "synonymMaps": [],
      "fields": []
    },
  ],
  "suggesters": [
    {
      "name": "my-index_suggester",
      "searchMode": "analyzingInfixMatching",
      "sourceFields": [
        "partnumbers"
      ]
    }
  ],
  "scoringProfiles": [
    {
      "name": "exactFirst",
      "functions": [],
      "functionAggregation": null,
      "text": {
        "weights": {
          "partnumbers": 2,
          "partialPartnumbers": 1,
        }
      }
    }
  ],
  "defaultScoringProfile": "exactFirst",
  "corsOptions": null,
  "analyzers": [
    {
      "@odata.type": "#Microsoft.Azure.Search.CustomAnalyzer",
      "name": "standardCmAnalyzer",
      "tokenizer": "standard_v2",
      "tokenFilters": [
        "lowercase",
        "asciifolding"
      ],
      "charFilters": []
    },
    {
      "@odata.type": "#Microsoft.Azure.Search.CustomAnalyzer",
      "name": "prefixCmAnalyzer",
      "tokenizer": "standard_v2",
      "tokenFilters": [
        "lowercase",
        "asciifolding",
        "edgeNGramCmTokenFilter"
      ],
      "charFilters": []
    }
  ],
  "charFilters": [],
  "tokenFilters": [
    {
      "@odata.type": "#Microsoft.Azure.Search.EdgeNGramTokenFilterV2",
      "name": "edgeNGramCmTokenFilter",
      "minGram": 2,
      "maxGram": 20,
      "side": "front"
    }
  ],
  "tokenizers": [],
  "@odata.etag": "\"0x8D8184F367A74XX\""
}
```

Now I am struggling to find a way (through a specific syntax? an analyzer? a tokenizer?) to be able to find all the files that have a **partnumbers** metadata field which contains one single SKU (so that I can retrive all documents related to one product): I'd like to pass the SKU "102938" to Azure Search and it would return me all the files that have this SKU in its **partnumbers** metadata field (potentially among others SKU).

But I have a hard time finding examples on Google, and the documentation seems - for now - a bit out my league (I am not really sure to understand properly what are analylyzers, tokenizers, etc and how they work! This is the first time I dig into the "search" world...).

So I would really appreciate of the community could help me on this, I'd be keen to read articles for beginners to understand everyhting, or tutorials, or anything that could help me move forward with this!

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, I just tried something that works: I defined the [**pattern** analyzer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/search/index-add-custom-analyzers#AnalyzerTable) on my **partnumbers** field, and when I tested with the [Analyzer Text API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/searchservice/test-analyzer), it did split my SKUs into several tokens.
And after that I could search for one SKU and it gave me back all the files I wanted!
Here is my index JSON definition:

```
{
  "name": "my-index",
  "fields": [
    {
      "name": "partnumbers",
      "type": "Edm.String",
      "facetable": true,
      "filterable": true,
      "key": false,
      "retrievable": true,
      "searchable": true,
      "sortable": true,
      "analyzer": "pattern",
      "indexAnalyzer": null,
      "searchAnalyzer": null,
      "synonymMaps": [],
      "fields": []
    },
    {
      "name": "metadata_storage_name",
      "type": "Edm.String",
      "facetable": true,
      "filterable": true,
      "key": false,
      "retrievable": true,
      "searchable": true,
      "sortable": true,
      "analyzer": null,
      "indexAnalyzer": null,
      "searchAnalyzer": null,
      "synonymMaps": [],
      "fields": []
    },
    {
      "name": "metadata_storage_content_type",
      "type": "Edm.String",
      "facetable": true,
      "filterable": true,
      "key": false,
      "retrievable": true,
      "searchable": true,
      "sortable": true,
      "analyzer": null,
      "indexAnalyzer": null,
      "searchAnalyzer": null,
      "synonymMaps": [],
      "fields": []
    },
    {
      "name": "metadata_storage_last_modified",
      "type": "Edm.String",
      "facetable": true,
      "filterable": true,
      "key": false,
      "retrievable": true,
      "searchable": true,
      "sortable": true,
      "analyzer": null,
      "indexAnalyzer": null,
      "searchAnalyzer": null,
      "synonymMaps": [],
      "fields": []
    },
    {
      "name": "metadata_storage_path",
      "type": "Edm.String",
      "facetable": true,
      "filterable": true,
      "key": false,
      "retrievable": true,
      "searchable": true,
      "sortable": true,
      "analyzer": null,
      "indexAnalyzer": null,
      "searchAnalyzer": null,
      "synonymMaps": [],
      "fields": []
    },
    {
      "name": "metadata_storage_size",
      "type": "Edm.Int64",
      "facetable": true,
      "filterable": true,
      "retrievable": true,
      "sortable": true,
      "analyzer": null,
      "indexAnalyzer": null,
      "searchAnalyzer": null,
      "synonymMaps": [],
      "fields": []
    },
    {
      "name": "key",
      "type": "Edm.String",
      "facetable": true,
      "filterable": true,
      "key": true,
      "retrievable": true,
      "searchable": true,
      "sortable": true,
      "analyzer": null,
      "indexAnalyzer": null,
      "searchAnalyzer": null,
      "synonymMaps": [],
      "fields": []
    },
    {
      "name": "name",
      "type": "Edm.String",
      "facetable": true,
      "filterable": true,
      "key": false,
      "retrievable": true,
      "searchable": true,
      "sortable": true,
      "analyzer": null,
      "indexAnalyzer": null,
      "searchAnalyzer": null,
      "synonymMaps": [],
      "fields": []
    },
    {
      "name": "partialPartnumbers",
      "type": "Edm.String",
      "facetable": false,
      "filterable": false,
      "key": false,
      "retrievable": false,
      "searchable": true,
      "sortable": false,
      "analyzer": null,
      "indexAnalyzer": "prefixCmAnalyzer",
      "searchAnalyzer": "standardCmAnalyzer",
      "synonymMaps": [],
      "fields": []
    },
    {
      "name": "partialName",
      "type": "Edm.String",
      "facetable": false,
      "filterable": false,
      "key": false,
      "retrievable": false,
      "searchable": true,
      "sortable": false,
      "analyzer": null,
      "indexAnalyzer": "prefixCmAnalyzer",
      "searchAnalyzer": "standardCmAnalyzer",
      "synonymMaps": [],
      "fields": []
    }
  ],
  "suggesters": [
    {
      "name": "conformity-certificates-index_suggester",
      "searchMode": "analyzingInfixMatching",
      "sourceFields": [
        "name"
      ]
    }
  ],
  "scoringProfiles": [
    {
      "name": "exactFirst",
      "functions": [],
      "functionAggregation": null,
      "text": {
        "weights": {
          "partnumbers": 4,
          "partialPartnumbers": 3,
          "name": 2,
          "partialName": 1
        }
      }
    }
  ],
  "defaultScoringProfile": "exactFirst",
  "corsOptions": null,
  "analyzers": [
    {
      "@odata.type": "#Microsoft.Azure.Search.CustomAnalyzer",
      "name": "standardCmAnalyzer",
      "tokenizer": "standard_v2",
      "tokenFilters": [
        "lowercase",
        "asciifolding"
      ],
      "charFilters": []
    },
    {
      "@odata.type": "#Microsoft.Azure.Search.CustomAnalyzer",
      "name": "prefixCmAnalyzer",
      "tokenizer": "standard_v2",
      "tokenFilters": [
        "lowercase",
        "asciifolding",
        "edgeNGramCmTokenFilter"
      ],
      "charFilters": []
    }
  ],
  "charFilters": [],
  "tokenFilters": [
    {
      "@odata.type": "#Microsoft.Azure.Search.EdgeNGramTokenFilterV2",
      "name": "edgeNGramCmTokenFilter",
      "minGram": 2,
      "maxGram": 20,
      "side": "front"
    }
  ],
  "tokenizers": [],
  "@odata.etag": "\"0x8D818EC80CXXXX\""
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can search for your part numbers with a regular filter.

$filter=search.in(partnumbers, '102938', ',')

You'll find more examples in the documentation here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/search/search-query-odata-filter

Do not use wildcards or regular expressions for this use case. Your example have partnumbers with varying length. So a wildcard search for 102938* would unintentionally also match 1029381, 10293810, 102938123 and so on.

Your data already explicitly and precisely list a set of part numbers. You can query against that list.

Answer (score 0):

This should be achievable through Regular expression & Wildcard search

This can be applied to any searchable field having [Lucene](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/search/search-lucene-query-architecture) query analyzer configured on the index.

"....The Full Lucene query language, which you get by setting queryType=full, extends the default Simple query language by adding support for more operators and query types like wildcard, fuzzy, regex, and field-scoped queries. For example, a regular expression sent in Simple query syntax would be interpreted as a query string and not an expression. The example request in this article uses the Full Lucene query language."

fieldName:searchExpression

e.g. searchFields=partnumbers&$select=partnumbers&search=partnumbers:102938*

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/search/query-lucene-syntax